# View scoped bean is not getting destroyed

Tags: jsf-2

I am using JSF 2.1 and primefaces 3.4.

All my xhtml views consist of layout which has header,left side navigation panel,footer and content.The managed beans are in **view scope**.

In most of my views, I am using **f:event** listener of type **preRenderView** to intialize certain attributes and services. In the listener, I have conditional statement to check for **postback** request. It exceutes the complete code inside **preRenderView** listener only when the request is not **postback**.

Even if I navigate to any other page (from let's say page **A** to page **B**) via left side navigation panel link, the **view scope** doesn't get destroyed and when I again return back to page **A**, the check for **postback** request returns **true**.Not sure why it is happening.

Appreciated if someone can help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: add new param to the link of returned back page and check on it in your init inside check for postback

Comment: I'm curious to know how you determined that _view scope doesn't get destroyed_ as well. Is it because `@PreDestroy` is never called or some other reason?

Comment: Thanks @rdcrng.Yes PreDestroy is not getting called, but came to know now that it's destroying the bean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to navigate by GET instead of POST.

I.e., use `<h:link>` or `<h:button>` instead of `<h:commandLink>` or `<h:commandButton>` for plain page-to-page navigation. This way the `isPostback()` will return `false`.

Further, you're not clear on how you've observed that the view scoped bean is not getting destroyed. Have you placed a debug breakpoint on bean's constructor to see if it's invoked when the new page is requested? If it is really exactly the same instance, then that can only happen if you're actually conditionally including a new page instead of really navigating to a physically different view.

Comment: Thanks @BalusC. Actually, it's destroying the bean. I checked using debug breakpoint on bean's constructor but it's doesn't call PreDestroy. Also, If I use <h:link>, isPostback returns false but I have to navigate conditionally(let's say I have 2 home page with different view) and also I have do certain operation before navigation and put the result in session. What could be the best way to do it?

Comment: My problem is solved now. I am still using commandLink for page navigation but now instead of using action, I am using actionListener and then inside this listener, I am using re-direct for navigation once everything is processed and put in the session.